# How do I change CKEditor so that it doesn't automatically put <p></p> inside the textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I'm following the tutorial of CKEditor, and I did this:

```
 $( '#editor' ).ckeditor(function(){});  //great works!!
```

But now...when I submit the form...I see that by default, the textarea has `<p></p>`. How do I make it "nothing" by default?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the following config values:

```
CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
CKEDITOR.config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```

Make sure that you clear your browser cache when you modify them as changes might not be picked up automatically.

Comment: Hi Darin, sorry I meant...how can I get rid of the default wrapper? (on init, I want nothing inside the textarea).  Right now, on init there is a <p></p> inside the textarea

Comment: But this is nice to know (please leave your current answer up here, this is good reference!)

Answer (score 1):

I am using this

```
CKEDITOR.instances.MainContent_notificationText.setData( '' );
```

for my non-jQuery plugin version and it works great.

For your jQuery plugin you could use

```
$('#editor').ckeditor(function(){
  this.setData("");
});
```